# Adding variable as a parameter to a function in PHP

Tags: php, function, parameters, scope

I have a very simple code to validate username and password,in that I have to specify  a *variable* as a *parameter* to a *function*,why should I specify ? since the rule of *functions* is that it can  access any *variable* outside other *function* and I have even *constants* that need not to be specified as a *parameter*. But my code doesn't work without *parameters* specified and *constants* work without being specified as a *parameter*.

```
//constants
    define('USERNAME','guruprasath');
    define('PASSWORD','123456');
//functions
    function login_check ($username,$password) {
        return USERNAME==$username && PASSWORD==$password ;
    }
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {
    $username = $_POST['name'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

        if( login_check($username,$password) ) {  //why specify the $username and $password parameter,but not specify for the constants
            $_SESSION['username']=$username;
            header('Location:admin.php');
        }
        else {
            echo 'your password or email  is wrong';
        }
}
```

Comment: Constants have globals scope automatically, because they're constants, so there's no need to pass them from function to function as arguments. Quoting from the [PHP Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php): `Like superglobals, the scope of a constant is global. You can access constants anywhere in your script without regard to scope.`

Comment: As your program grows you can't just depend on globals (defining every variable as a global would create a huge list and would be chaotic). This is when you need to start using objects and methods with there own scopes and variables. To coordinate the variables you'll need to pass them along by the means of methods.

Comment: Though variables are not super global at least it can be accessed with in functions, then what is the use of specifying a _parameter_,why should it be specified by specifying is the _variable_ being converted to super global. @MarkBaker

Comment: The point of constants is that they will never change during the execution of your script; variables can and do change: in your example, `$username` and `$password` are defined based on user input.... but it isn't good to make all your variables global, because that's a way of introducing subtle bugs into your script when something changes them and you need to find out where and why.... whereas variables passed as arguments are under your control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions have their own variables scope and cant access variables outside of it except if these variables are constants or globals like $_POST, $_GET, etc.

If you want to change your function not to use parameters, you can do it like this:

```
function login_check () {
    return USERNAME==$_POST['username'] && PASSWORD==$_POST['password'] ;
}
```

You can read more in the PHP [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Comment: is this same in **javascript**.

Comment: a = 5; getA = function() {  return a; } would work in JS, but not in PHP so - no, it does not work the same way